# kendo ui validation message position

Tags: validation, user-interface, kendo-ui

how can I set the validation message position ?such as right.the default is bottom, but  has an corvered mask on my input control ,that is very unusefull.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRhhT.png)

Answer (score 1):

use this

data-placement="top" on the

```
<input class=" pink-tooltip" id="txt_mobile_No"   data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"  placeholder="Mobile Number" />
```